# Java File/IO/NIO API for writing to files that can be read by other programs in real time

Tags: java, logging, file-io, nio, tail

I am working with a Java console application that must write (append) to two separate files, corresponding to `OUT` and `ERR` streams. External utilities like `tail` and `grep` will be monitoring these files in real-time. I started out writing to these two streams via the `Appendable` interface, but then it seems like the files don't reflect any changes until the application finishes execution, following a flush and close on the output streams.

**Service**

```
package com.mycompany;

public class Service {

                private Appendable outlog;
                private Appendable errlog;

                public Service(Appendable outlog, Appendable errlog) {
                        this.outlog = outlog;
                        this.errlog = errlog;
                }

                public void executeTask() throws Exception {

                                outlog.append("task execution started\n");
                                Thread.sleep(30 * 1000);
                                outlog.append("task execution completed\n");
                }
}
```

**Application**

```
package com.mycompany;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

                PrintWriter outlog = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("application.log")));
                PrintWriter errlog = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("application-err.log")));

                Service service = new Service(outlog, errlog);
                service.executeTask();

                outlog.flush();
                outlog.close();
                errlog.flush();
                errlog.close();
        }
}
```

Is my design fundamentally wrong or should I be doing this in a better and more efficient manner?

Comment: have you tried using logging libraries out there: slf4j, logback, log4j?

Comment: The application has control over the names of these __log__ files, so logging libraries will not be very helpful in that context. Multiple files will be generated, based on the time of execution and user identity.

Comment: Have you tried flushing without closing? For example, flush after each write to the log?

Comment: @Kenster I tried that and it does not help. Only `close()` appeared to make the file contents instantly accessible. Which is not practical to do for every `append()` operation.

Comment: Calling `flush()` really ought to work to flush the output to disk. Any chance this is on Windows? Or are the log files being written to a network filesystem like NFS, with the reader on another host? The code that you posted doesn't actually compile and I suspect it's pseudo-code. Could you edit your question to include an actual working example program?

Comment: @Kenster I have posted the entire code for the two Java files. Here is the other wrinkle to the problem... `Service.java` is passed an `Appendable` so it should only know to append to it. It should not be expected to perform `.flush()` operations on the passed in `Appendable`.

Comment: Files contents become visible to other processes if you get the FileDescriptor and call the sync() method after each write followed by a flush. You shouldn't have to close the file.

Comment: @fredt can you provide some sample code to illustrate that, possibly in the context of the above example application?

Comment: @OP, search SO for `filedescriptor sync` to see examples. Use it after each flush.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Service` class, declare and propagate the `outlog` and `errlog` fields as `Writer` (which implemets `Appendable`) and call `outlog.flush()` after appending you message.

```
public class Service {

  private Writer outlog;
  private Writer errlog;

  public Service(Writer outlog, Writer errlog) {
    this.outlog = outlog;
    this.errlog = errlog;
  }

  public void executeTask() throws Exception {
    try {
      outlog.append("task execution started\n");
      outlog.append("task execution completed\n");
    finally {
      outlog.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is it worth overriding the `.append()` method by sub-classing PrintWriter? That way, I can place a `.flush()` in the overridden method unbeknownst to the `service`.